# All files in Finder show 'Date Modified' with correct days but always the same hour: 19:08

Tags: macos, terminal, console

When I open a Finder window, all the file timestamps show the same hour, 19:08. The dates change, but the hour stays constant. This is also the case for time/dates shown in the Console.

The Clock on the top right shows the correct time.

A `date`command in Terminal shows the correct time.

I have zapped my NVRAM and also replaced the on-board battery.

I am using a MacPro 1,1 with Mac OS X 10.7.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour can be seem if the date is customised in the System Preferences / Language and Text pane.

To fix this - go to System Preferences, then Languages and Text.
Click 'Formats' tab, then the 'customise' button next to 'Times'.

You should see all the elements of the proposed time formats as having light blue backgrounds.  If you see any text on a plain background this is literal text rather than a placeholder.

On previous screen, the 'Formats' tab. Change 'Region' dropdown at top of page from 'Custom' to an appropriate region for you to give you a sensible set of defaults.

To fix and keep your customised settings, delete the plain text, and then drag and drop from blue placeholders to set your time formats.  Drag the hour placeholder, type a colon and drag the minute placeholder.

Comment: That was it! A thousand thanks, digitalsean - it was driving me mad!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in that NO time was showing at all in the Finder!

In Mojave, the pref pane is called Language and Region.
Click on **Advanced** tab at the bottom, then the **Times** tab at the top, then click the **Restore Defaults** button at the bottom. If the **Restore Defaults** button is highlighted, then you know that the time format has been messed with.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (yes, still using 10.7.5 in 2019...) All changes to files were dated somewhere in the 19:00 hour, as was the time displayed when in screen saver mode.

This solution also worked for me, but I wish to add that everything displayed under custom formats tab was already light blue. There was nothing to change, yet simply opening it up seems to have made the difference. I did delete and drag back in the (exact same) short time.

The fix has changed the times (created, modified, saved..) on my files retroactively as well.